# How to find the largest number of times a word is repeated consecutively in a given string?

Tags: python, string, cpu-word

Okay, so this is kind of a confusing question, I will try and word it in the best way that I can.

I'm trying to figure out a way that I can find the largest consecutive repeats of a word in a string in Python

For example, let's say the word I want to look for is "apple" and the string is: "**apple**bananaorangeorangeorangebanana**appleapple**orangeapple**appleappleapple**". Here, the largest number of consecutive repeats for the word "apple" is 3.

I have tried numerous ways of finding repeating character such as this:

```
word="100011010" #word = "1"
count=1
length=""
if len(word)>1:
    for i in range(1,len(word)):
       if word[i-1]==word[i]:
          count+=1
       else :
           length += word[i-1]+" repeats "+str(count)+", "
           count=1
    length += ("and "+word[i]+" repeats "+str(count))
else:
    i=0
    length += ("and "+word[i]+" repeats "+str(count))
print (length)
```

But this works with integers and not words. It also outputs the number of times the character repeats in general but does not identify the largest consecutive repeats. I hope that makes sense. My brain is kind of all over the place rn so I apologize if im trippin

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially "how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Work out how *you* do this on paper.  Look up the many examples of this problem on line.  "I don't know how to write this program" is not a valid SO question.  Translate your pencil & paper solution to code -- *that* can make a good posting.

Comment: Do you have a word list to search? Or is there any space between words in your string?

Comment: ^No there are not any spaces between the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I came up with that I believe solves your problem. There is almost certainly a simpler/faster way to do it if you spend more time with the problem which I would encourage.

```
import re

search_string = "applebananaorangeorangeorangebananaappleappleorangeappleappleappleapple"
search_term = "apple"


def search_for_term(search_string, search_term):
    #split string into array on search_term
    #keeps search term in array unlike normal string split
    split_string = re.split(f'({search_term})', search_string)

    #remove unnecessary characters
    split_string = list(filter(lambda x: x != "", split_string))

    #enumerate string and filter out instances that aren't the search term
    enum_string = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] == search_term, enumerate(split_string)))

    #loop through each of the items in the enumerated list and save to the current chain
    #once a chain brakes i.e. the next element is not in order append the current_chain to 
    #the chains list and start over
    chains = []
    current_chain = []
    for idx, val in enum_string:
        if len(current_chain) == 0:
            current_chain.append(idx)
        elif idx == current_chain[-1] + 1:
            current_chain.append(idx)
        else:
            chains.append(current_chain)
            current_chain = [idx]
        print(chains, current_chain)    

    #append anything leftover in the current_chain list to the chains list
    if len(current_chain) > 0:
        chains.append(current_chain)
        del current_chain

    #find the max length nested list in the chains list and return it
    max_length = max(map(len, chains)) 
    return max_length


max_length = search_for_term(search_string, search_term)    
print(max_length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this. first check for 'apple' in the randString, then check for 'appleapple', then 'appleappleapple', and so on until the search result is empty. Keep track of the iteration count and voilà.

```
randString = "applebananaorangeorangeorangebananaappleappleorangeappleappleappleapple"
find = input('type in word to search for: ')


def consecutive():
    count =0

    for i in range(len(randString)):
        count +=1
        seachword = [find*count]
        check = [item for item in seachword if item in randString]

        if len(check) != 0:
            continue

        else:
            # Need to remove 1 from the final count.
            print (find, ":", count -1)
            break

consecutive()
```